# JQuery submit button with condition

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to put a condition in with a jQuery submit button and can't seem to make anything work. If `medLength == 0` then there should be an error message. There is no error message and even if `medLength` has a value the submit button doesn't work. The submit button has a graphic so I can't change it to a button. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$("#submit").click(function get() {
    if (medLength == 0) {
        $(".errorStop").css().show;
    } else {

        $.ajax({
            url: "postnew1.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                type: medType,
                time: medLength,
                length: counter
            },
        }).success(function (response) {
            location.href = "meditate.php";
        }).error(function (e) {});
    }
});
```

The code below does work without the `if/else` statement:

```
$("#submit").click(function get() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "postnew1.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            type: medType,
            time: medLength,
            length: counter
        },
    }).success(function (response) {
        location.href = "meditate.php";
    }).error(function (e) {});
});
```

Comment: I think you should do : if  (medLength.length == 0){

Comment: Has it occurred to you to check what `medLength` contains before using it?

Answer (score 1):

One way to debug this would be to add `alert("Error")` to the if case, so you can verify if that code is indeed being triggered, like this:

```
if  (medLength ==0){
    alert("Error");
    $(".errorStop").css().show;         
}
```

But I am able to see that part of the reason your error message might not be showing is because you aren't calling the show() function.

Change

```
$(".errorStop").css().show;
```

to

```
$(".errorStop").show();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be

```
   $(".errorStop").css().show;
```

to

```
$(".errorStop").show();
```

Hoping you are getting the `medLength` right!

Answer (score 0):

"The submit button has a graphic so I can't change it to a button.". You dont need the "button" to be a type="button" or type="submit". Said that you can set a id to the element, like id="btn_sendInfo", for example. I did not understand where medLength value came from. So this code should work:

NOte= the type. I set json, but if you dont want you can change as you desire, or erase and let jquery "gess", deal with that.
If you dont want send data fron server using jason you can erase //JSON loop to retrieve information.

```
//Your javaScript code
$(document).on("click", "#btn_sendInfo", function(){

if(medLength === 0){
    $( ".errorStop" ).show()
}
else{

    //Data you want to send to php evaluate
     var dt={ 
              ObjEvn:"btn_sendInfo", //You can use $ObjEvn=$_POST[ObjEvn] on server side php and test if($ObjEvn="btn_sendInfo"){do something ....}
              type: medType,
              time: medLength,
              length: counter,
              OtherDataJsToPHP: $("#txt_EmailLogin").val()

            };

    //Ajax      
     var request =$.ajax({//http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
                            url: "postnew1.php",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: dt,
                            dataType: "json ????????"
                        });

    //Ajax Done catch JSON from PHP 
        request.done(function(dataset){

            // Put your succes function here ===> location.href = "meditate.php";

            //JSON Or if want to use json you cand use this to retrieve information send from server through json
            for (var index in dataset){ 
                 dataPHPtoJsJS=dataset[index].dataPHPtoJs;
                 asManyasYouWantJS=dataset[index].asYouWant;
             }


             //JavaScript conditions. Here you can control the behaivior of your html object, based on your PHP response
             if(dataPHPtoJsJS){
                $( "#idYourHtmlElement" ).removeClass( "class1" )
                $( "#idYourHtmlElement" ).addClass( "class2" )
             }


     }); 

    //Ajax Fail 
        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            //Put your function ---- function (e) {}
            alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
        }); 
    }

}
```

But if you want only solve your issue do this, despite your seconde code:

```
$(document).on("click", "#sendInfo", function(){

if(medLength === 0){
    $( ".errorStop" ).show()
}
else{
        //your ajax code
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As shown by the following demo, an image button works just as a submit button and does submit the parent form.

Secondly, the demo also shows the code within the submit handler is conditional; different parts of the code is executed at different clicks, depending on the value of a variable.

Therefore, this demo should serve as a good example to help you accomplish what you had originally intended.

```js
var medLength = 0;
  $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if( medLength === 0 ) {
      alert('medLength = 0');
    } else {
      alert('medLength != 0');
    }
    medLength++;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  First name:
  <input type="text" name="fname">
  <br>
  <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQnMxVaix7dQzuVgQa5rwGcrX6sdy5vlvel5djnQgcn926d1FgH" alt="Submit">
</form>
```